# C++ Students score average calculator array problem

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that calculates students last scores as a midterm, quiz1, quiz2 and final then finds their class average depends on a number of students. Program will show the class average. User should enter the scores. I am new to c++, and my problem is right now i can't find a way to connect this for loop to an array for class average. Is my code wrong for this? I don't know what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mt, q1, q2, fnl, stdn, num;
    double cls[5], std, avg;

    cout << "Enter a number of students: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (stdn=0; stdn<num; stdn++) {
        cout<<"Enter mt, q1, q2, fnl of a "<<stdn+1<<". student in order:"<<endl;
        cin>>mt>>q1>>q2>>fnl;

        std = mt * 30/100 + q1 * 10/100 + q2 * 10/100 + fnl * 50/100;

        cout<<stdn+1<<". students total score is "<<std<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is, most likely, suffering from integer division.

Comment: Note this is a very different thing from Joy Division.

Answer (score 1):

Type int is always rounding down the value after a decimal point.
So, (int)3.84 == 3, and therefore your std variable will probably have a wrong value.
Define all variables as double for start. To calculate avg simply add marks then devide by the number of students in the end.

```
double mt, q1, q2, fnl, stdn, num, grades_sum = 0, avg;
...
for(stdn=0; stdn<num; stdn++){
    ...
    grades_sum += mt * 30/100 + q1 * 10/100 + q2 * 10/100 + fnl * 50/100;
    ...
}
avg = grades_sum/num;
```

Comment: Numbers are not the issue here i guess. Program should show all of the students average, then total average of their class. I can't connect these two, that my problem.

Comment: Not sure to which average you are referring, if a student has marks for q1, q2, mt, fnl, should'nt the program calculate the score he gets? then the average of the entire class? what other average is there?

Comment: It will calculate the average of students total score. I mean after we calculate the q1, q2, mt, fnl. Not just that. I can do that, thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array for class average. Just add up all the students scores and divide by the number of students. That just needs one variable (I've called it `std_sum`) not an array. Like this

```
double std_sum = 0.0;
for(stdn=0; stdn<num; stdn++){
    ...
   std = mt * 30/100 + q1 * 10/100 + q2 * 10/100 + fnl * 50/100;
   std_sum = std_sum + std; // add up all student scores
}
avg = std_total/num;
```

Comment: You mean entering the scores by myself? Will this stop letting user enter it?

Comment: No and no, but I don't really understand what you are asking. I'm showing you how to calculate the class average, this has nothing to do with how the scores are entered, it's just a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add up all of the students scores, then at the end divide by the total number of students. This will give you a total average of the class. Also, I avoided integer division by replacing your fractions with decimals that add up to 1. I also edited your for loop to start at 1 and go to the number, to avoid adding 1 to everything.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mt, q1, q2, fnl, stdn, num;
    double cls[5], std;
    double classAvg = 0; // add a new variable

    cout << "Enter a number of students: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (stdn=1; stdn <= num; stdn++) {
       cout << "Enter mt, q1, q2, fnl of a " << stdn << ". student in order:" << endl;
       cin >> mt >> q1 >> q2 >> fnl;
       std = (mt * 0.3) + (q1 * 0.1) + (q2 * 0.1) + (fnl * 0.5);
       cout << stdn << ". students total score is " << std << endl;

       classAvg = classAvg + std; // start adding the totals of all the students
    }
    avg = classAvg/num; // find the total average by dividing by total students
    cout << "Class Average is " << classAvg << endl; // display average.
}
```